# Django ModelForm inheritance and Meta inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-forms

I have this ModelForm:

```
class Event(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Event, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ##Here make some changes such as:
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        ##Many settings here which **i don't want to rewrite in 10 child classes**

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = something...
        widgets = some settings here also.
```

And this child ModelForm:

```
class UpgradedEvent(Event):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpgradedEvent,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    class Meta(Event.Meta):
        model = UpgradedEvent
```

`UpgradedEvent` is a child of `Event` **model** but has some extra fields.
How can i inherit all the settings from the `Event` FORM into `UpgradedEvent` FORM?

When running the above code, it renders the `Event` form. Is there a way to inherit only the settings inside `__init__` ?

> EDIT

Check out the answer, it works great but keep in mind:
you need to create another instance of `FormHelper` in your child class, otherwise it won't work. So child class should look something like:

```
class UpgradedEvent(Event):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpgradedEvent,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()

    class Meta(Event.Meta):
        model = UpgradedEvent
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `FormWithSettings` which will hold common settings for you form classes and inherit it

```
class FormWithSettings(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormWithSettings, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ##Here make some changes such as:
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        ##Many settings here which **i don't want to rewrite in 10 child classes**

    class Meta:
        exclude = something...
        widgets = some settings here also.

class EventForm(FormWithSettings):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    class Meta(FormWithSettings.Meta):
        model = Event

class UpgradedEventForm(FormWithSettings):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpgradedEventForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    class Meta(FormWithSettings.Meta):
        model = UpgradedEvent
```

Comment: The thing is i have many settings in `__init__` which i don't want to copy-paste in 10 child classes of `Event` Form.

Comment: I did try to implement this idea and i have absolutely no idea why it's not working. If i inherit the meta, it works, if i try `UpgradedEventForm(FormWithSettings)` i lose the extra fields from the Upgraded class and i have absolutely no idea why since they work fine if i just inherit the meta.

Comment: @MikeVlad post your actual code please, and what you expect of it

Comment: @i figured out, i ll edit the question. it was that i had to create another instance of `FormHelper` - Crispy Forms

Comment: I had to restart the django server to see changes

Comment: @Aseem yes, this the only way, otherwise your server would not have new code changes

Answer (score 11):

You can obtain the fields the `Meta` above, and extend the lists, etc.:

```
class UpgradedEventForm(EventForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpgradedEventForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        # some extra settings
        # ...
        # for example
        self.fields['extra_field'].initial = 'initial value of extra field'

    class Meta(EventForm.Meta):
        model = UpgradedEvent
        exclude = EventForm.Meta.exclude + ['extra_exclude1', 'extra_exclude2']
        fields = EventForm.Meta.fields + ['extra_field']
```

So by using inheritance, we can add extra procedures to the `__init__` function by performing some extra actions after the `super(UpgradedEventForm, self)` call, and wwe can access the attributes of our parent, and extend these.

Note that you better name your forms with a `Form` suffix, since now your models clash with your forms. As a result, your `Form` seems to have as model a reference to the `Form` itself. By using proper "*nomenclature*", you avoid a lot of mistakes.